# SITE_ROOT = Variable?

Tags: php

I'd very much appreciate if someone could help me with a solution.

How can I get this:

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . SITE_BASE);
```

to look something like this:

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', [variable from root.com/directory/data.php] );
```

Many thanks.

Comment: you want to use a variable from another php script?  You would need to include said script, the variable would carry over. Whats the problem here?

Comment: I've done that, but had no joy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include_once("/directory/data.php");
    define('SITE_ROOT', $variable);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately this doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: It should work in all cases theoretically, post some code maybe?

Comment: Here's my code: include_once ("/directory/data.php"); define ('SITE_ROOT', $variable); require_once SITE_ROOT . '/include/file.php'; Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: do a `var_dump($variable)` after `include`ing the page and see where that gets you.

Comment: Can you verify the file is being included? Try switching `include` to `require`, or add an `echo "hello";` to the included file just to check. This solution should be working for you.