# SITE_ROOT = URL + Variable?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SITE_ROOT = Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563220/site-root-variable)

How can I get this:

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . SITE_BASE);
```

to look something like this:

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', [variable from domain.com/dir/data.php] );
```

I'd very much appreciate if someone could help me with a solution.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the content of `data.php`?

Comment: The variable I need to insert contains a URL. Thanks.

Comment: One variable? Or two variables: Document root and site base? What name/label has/have that/these variable(s)?

Comment: One variable. The variable IS the SITE_ROOT. There are lots of areas on my system that use this variable to function, but just one wouldn't work using it alone, so I used the SITE_ROOT command, but now my include files aren't in the root, they are in a sub-directory. So I need to be able to change the URL in that variable and everything on the system still work, irrespective of where the include files are located. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: This questions is nonsense - if you know how defines, includes and variables work then you just need to put it all together.

Comment: It's not nonsense. If you think it is, then don't waste your valuable time. I know what data needs to be in the code, I just don't know how to construct it in PHP. I am not a PHP expert. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to include the data.php file before you define the SITE_ROOT constant. Like this:

```
<?php
   require_once('data.php');
   define('SITE_ROOT', $yourVariableFromDataDotPHP); 
?>
```

Although it looks a bit weird...don't know the context of course.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've tried this already, but it doesn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not an error message your browser will produce..maybe you can specify what the real error message is and we can be more of a help.

Comment: There is no error message. The area of the page simply doesn't appear. Thank you.

Comment: maybe some web development tools for your browser would help?